# Trouble with android openGL if statement nd onTouch event

Tags: android, opengl-es, if-statement, floating-point

I have created a 3D cube in Android openGL which I can turn on the X-Axis using a onTouch event, but I want to use it as a UI, for example I am trying to get it so that when one face is facing the camera if you tap the surface it works as a onClick listener, but I am having trouble with the if statement I am using to check what face is facing the camera, my entire class for it is as follows:

```
public class GLCubeEx extends Activity {

GLSurfaceView ourSurface;
GLCubeEx This = this;




public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ourSurface = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    ourSurface.setRenderer(new GLCubeRenderer());
    setContentView(ourSurface);





}
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

     float touchedX = 0;
     float touchedY = 0;

     Button btn = new Button(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsd = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        paramsd.height = 60;
        paramsd.width = 120;

        btn.setLayoutParams(paramsd);
        addContentView(btn, paramsd);


    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
         GLCubeRenderer.xAngle = (touchedX - event.getX())/2f;
           GLCubeRenderer.yAngle = (touchedY - event.getY())/2f;

       } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
           GLCubeRenderer.xAngle = (touchedX - event.getX())/2f;
           GLCubeRenderer.yAngle = (touchedY - event.getY())/2f;

           touchedX = event.getX();
           touchedY = event.getY();

}






 **EDIT here, thaks to Laurence pointing out** 
    if(GLCubeRenderer.xAngle > -118f && GLCubeRenderer.xAngle < -65f){

        btn.setText("working");


    }

    String s = Float.toString(GLCubeRenderer.xAngle);
    btn.setText(s);


    return true;


}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ourSurface.onPause();
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ourSurface.onResume();
}
```

}

The trouble i'm having is that the the if statement in my motion event that checks whether the variable xAngle (which is a float created when swiping the sceen and used tto rotate the cube) is between two values is not being triggered, btn is a button in app that displays the value of xAngle, I can't ee why it isn't being triggered any ideas or obvious solutions that i haven't seen?

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger, or even logging some of the values to see what's going on?

Comment: Yer i'm logging the values and I ran the eclipse debug tool with break points, but I still can't trigger it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible:

```
GLCubeRenderer.xAngle < -118f && GLCubeRenderer.xAngle > -65f
```

You probably meant:

```
GLCubeRenderer.xAngle > -118f && GLCubeRenderer.xAngle < -65f
```

Comment: True, but it still hasn't solved my problem, which is strange

Answer (score 0):

Every cycle of on touch sets the text of the button to the angle, how are you checking if your if statement is executing, because right after you set text to working its gona set it to the angle right after, im not sure, just some input here

Comment: I believe that it sets the text of the button when if I rotate the cube within the parameters of the  if statement and leave it i shouldn't be to difficult, but that is a very good point I will change it to log some string data instead.

Comment: i tried it and it is working! it's just that the button onclickListener was not perhaps because it's inside a onTouch event, so i would need to be touching the cube as well as pressing the button?

Comment: yeah, dont forget to mark your answer if its answered and give up1's to all the info you used while looking through this site, i wasnt allowed to ask questions for a while because of that